# Linq To Entities Exclude Related Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I am building an ASP.Net MVC 3 Web application which uses Entity Framework 4.1. I also use the Unit of Work pattern with a Generic Repository. I have two Entities in my Model, **Shift** and **ShiftDate**. Please see the diagram below for their structure. The idea is, a **Shift** can have 1 or many **ShiftDates**, and a **ShiftDate** can belong to only one **Shift**.

[image]

I wish to create a query which will return a List of all **Shifts** like so

```
public IList<Shift> GetShifts(int id)
{
   return _UoW.Shifts.Get(s => s.organisationID == id).OrderBy(s => s.startDate).ToList();
}
```

Then in my Razor View, I wish to use a foreach loop and list the details of each Shift. One of these details is the total number of **ShiftDates** each **Shift** has. To do this I will do something like

```
foreach(var shiftDate in Model.Shifts)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShiftDates.Count)
}
```

This works fine, however, I want the count to exclude **ShiftDates** whose shiftDateStatusID is set to 442. To do this I tried amending my Linq Query to this

```
return _UoW.Shifts.Get(s => s.organisationID == id && s.ShiftDates.Any(sd => sd.shiftDateStatusID != 442))
.OrderBy(s => s.startDate).ToList();
```

However, this still pulls back ShiftDates who have a shiftDateStatusID of 442.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
_UoW.Shifts.Get(s => s.organisationID == id
                     && s.ShiftDates.Any(sd => sd.shiftDateStatusID != 442)
```

you get shifts that have at least one `ShiftDate` having a `shiftDateStatusID` other than 442. Well, there are probably a lot of shifts meeting this condition. The `ShiftDates` collections of these shifts will be loaded completely, including those with 442 (if any).

Either you have to exclude the `ShiftDate`s with status 442 when you populate your view model, or when it's only for the count, exclude them when you do the count:

```
item.ShiftDates.Count(sd => sd.shiftDateStatusID != 442)
```